# Multiple File Upload using @Context HttpServletRequest with @FormDataParam in jersey

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jersey, jax-rs

I have created a jersey restful web service where I **managed** to upload **multiple number of files** using `@Context HttpServletRequest request` as method signature which work nicely.
Thing is, to fetch other form fields I need to repetitively check with `.isFormField();` method with relative `.getName();` for file or `.getFieldName();`, and `.getString();` method to check whether required fields are present or not **every time the web service is called** which I think little lengthy and expensive process if there are several other fields.

Easier approach was to use `@FormDataParam` where webservice used to exposed with parameter which client need to pass but **problem** is I am not able to upload more than one file at one go.

Since Its also not possible to use `request.getParameter("field1");` to get other form fields if media type or enctype is `multipart/form-data`.

Whenever I tried to combine both `@FormDataParam` and `@Context HttpServletRequest request` together, it throws exception:
`org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream closed`
while parsing the **request** with `.parseRequest(request);` method of `ServletFileUpload` class.

Kindly suggest some good approach How can I achieve multiple file upload with getting required form fields as easy as `@FormDataParam` in jersey.

**approach for multiple file upload:**

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/multipleFiles")
public String restDemo(@Context HttpServletRequest request) 
{
  //...code goes here
}
```

**My form:**

[image]

**output:(after parsing request)**

> field1 > abc
>   field2 > xyz
>   Chrysanthemum.jpg Size: 879394
>   Desert.jpg Size: 845941
>   Hydrangeas.jpg Size: 595284
>   Jellyfish.jpg
>   Size: 775702

Comment: I don't really understand why you couldn't upload more than one file when using @FormDataParam? Does "Multiple files" mean you need variable number of files to be uploaded (user can click "add more files" in the form and get additional upload fields)?

Comment: @Jonas that is true that user can add more files from UI, but what approach should be followed to catch up with all the files using `@FormDataParam` ? As per my knowledge is concerned mapping of multiple file in single `@FormDataParam` is not possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the fields have the same name, like this:

```
<form name="formtest" action="rest/multipleFiles" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="atext" value="abc" />
    <input type="text" name="btext" value="123" />
    <input type="file" name="zfile" value="" />
    <input type="file" name="zfile" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

You can use:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/multipleFiles")    
public String restDemo(@FormDataParam("zfile") List<FormDataBodyPart> zfile)
```

Now, I advise against using HttpServletRequest. If you need to process everything, use this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)    
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/multipleFiles")
public String restDemo(FormDataMultiPart formParams) {
    formParams.getFields();
}
```

Comment: can you please explain why one should not use `HttpServletRequest` as I know that I cannot process it for other details, but is there any other harm of using it ?

Comment: If you use HttpServletRequest mixed with Jersey, it may close streams, buffers, before you can use them. Because JAX-RS was made to avoid using the Servlet directly. Now, there are cases that you may need to interact with a servlet directly, but only if necessary. It all depends on your web container and JAX-RS implementation, Tomcat/Glassfish/JBoss vs Jersey/CXF/Resteasy.

Comment: +1 for explaining why not use `HttpServletRequest` in jax-rs your reason is true as I have faced this same problem.

Comment: What if the number of files is variable?

Comment: @Maxrunner use `List<FormDataBodyPart>`

Comment: Thanks, but i ended using the json that im passing with info on the documents to get the files. That way i don't need to iterate on the list of parts.

Comment: How do you access the FileInputStream you would regularly get as a method parameter for single file uploads? @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputFile, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail